# How to fix Entities and POJOs must have a usable public constructor

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin

I got this error when I tried to launch my app while using sqlite database.

I have 3 data classes in seperate files:

```
@Entity(tableName = "movies")
data class MovieNews(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int? = null,
    @SerializedName("movie_db")
    @Embedded(prefix = "movies_")
    val movies: List<Movies>? = null,
)

data class Movies(
    val description: String? = null,
    @Embedded(prefix = "actors_")
    val actors: List<Actors>? = null,

)

data class Actors(
    val name: String? = null
    val age: Int? = null
)
```

When I launched the app I got the error:

> error: Entities and POJOs must have a usable public constructor. You
>   can have an empty constructor or a constructor whose parameters match
>   the fields (by name and type). - java.util.List

How can I fix this error?

Don't know if this is related to the problem, but I have this warning

> w: [kapt] Incremental annotation processing requested, but
>   support is disabled because the following processors are not
>   incremental: androidx.room.RoomProcessor (DYNAMIC).

I also saw bunch of questions about this error, none  of them solved my problem

**UPDATE:**

If I comment out the Embedded line, the app does compile.

I dug into stackoverflow questions and what I found that probably there is a problem with `Embedded` and Lists.

```
   @SerializedName("movie_db")
    @Embedded(prefix = "movies_")
    val movies: List<Movies>? = null,
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general case:

```
data class MyDataClass(
  var myfield: String
){
  constructor(myfield: String): this(myfield)
}
```

For your data classes: Just provide a default value in the constructor:

```
@Entity(tableName = "movies")
data class MovieNews(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int? = null,
    @SerializedName("movie_db")
    @Embedded(prefix = "movies_")
    val movies: List<Movies>? = null,
){
  constructor(): this(0, "", listOf())
}

data class Movies(
    val description: String? = null,
    @Embedded(prefix = "actors_")
    val actors: List<Actors>? = null,
) // same

data class Actors(
    val name: String? = null
    val age: Int? = null
) //same
```

**Why does this happen?** Because Room doesn't know how to tell the Java generated code how to initialize null fields (Java does not support default values)

If you don't like the solution: Just remove the `?` and make everything a `val` BUT provide a default value.

The second thing is unrelated to your problem but can be fixed by adding:

```
javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = [
                        "room.schemaLocation"  : "$projectDir/schemas".toString(),
                        "room.incremental"     : "true",
                        "room.expandProjection": "true"]
            }
        }
```

In your `build.gradle`

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, but unfortunately none of the answer works for me.  See my update about the embedded line, maybe it can direct you the right direction

Comment: Does this article help?

https://www.coroutinedispatcher.com/2019/08/solving-room-cannot-find-setter-for.html