# How to resolve "Entities and POJOs must have a usable public constructor"

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I have seen this question [several](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61480808/317027) times on SO. however the solution doesn't seem to apply to my problem.

I have a Kotlin data-class that is used as an Entity in Room

```
@Entity(tableName = "training_session")
data class SessionEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false) val id: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "current_state_marker") val currentState: Short,
    @Embedded val states: List<Int>
)
```

It is producing

```
> Task :training-infrastructure:kaptDebugKotlin FAILED
error: Entities and POJOs must have a usable public constructor. You can have an empty constructor or a constructor whose parameters match the fields (by name and type). - java.util.List
error: Entities and POJOs must have a usable public constructor. You can have an empty constructor or a constructor whose parameters match the fields (by name and type). - java.util.List
```

In the same project I have a very similar entity which also has a list and that doesn't produce any errors.

---

Tried out the answer provided by [MikeT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69958933/317027), for me it required a small [change](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45071364/317027) in the way the converters were defined

```
data class SessionStateList (val stateList : List<Int>) 

class SessionStateListConverter {

    @TypeConverter
    fun fromArraySessionStateList(sh: List<Int>?): String? {
        return Gson().toJson(sh)
    }
    @TypeConverter
    fun toArraySessionStateList(sh: String?): List<Int>? {
        val listType: Type = object : TypeToken<ArrayList<Int?>?>() {}.type
        return Gson().fromJson(sh,listType)
    }
}
```

---

A quick follow-up.  I had mentioned that I have another Entity that has an `Embedded val something: List<Int>` and I had not noticed any compiler errors.

The reason, I had not noticed any compiler errors was because the entity was not included in the `@Database` annotation.

Comment: A simple fix for the immediate error might be to use an `ArrayList`. `List` is an interface and has no constructor. “error: Entities .. must have a usable public constructor .. - java.util.List”

Comment: Do you have a `TypeConverter` registered on the `RoomDatabase` that converts `List<Int>` to something that Room can use?

Comment: Although getting to the “end goal” probably involves some mapping to meaningfully associate a list to an SQL table.. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44986626/android-room-database-how-to-handle-arraylist-in-an-entity

Comment: @user2864740 - good point - that escaped me, but changing it created another issue "error: Cannot find setter for field. - size in java.util.ArrayList".  Also the link you provided proved to be helpful in mapping the array - thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot have a List/Array etc as a column type. So your issue is centred on `@Embedded val states: List<Int>`

You could have a POJO e.g. StatesHolder :-

```
data class StatesHolder(
    val stateList: List<Int>
)
```

and then have

```
@Entity(tableName = "training_session")
data class SessionEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false) val id: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "current_state_marker") val currentState: Short,
    val states: StatesHolder
)
```

- Note that you cannot Embed StatesHolder as then that just inserts List. If you want to Embed then you have to Embed a wrapper that uses a StatesHolder.

You will then need TypeConverters to convert to and from a StatesHolder object to a type that can be stored. Probably a String and Probably a JSON respresentation of the StatesHold object e.g.

```
class Converters {

    @TypeConverter
    fun fromStatesHolder(sh: StatesHolder): String {
        return Gson().toJson(sh)
    }
    @TypeConverter
    fun toStatesHolder(sh: String): StatesHolder {
        return Gson().fromJson(sh,StatesHolder::class.java)
    }
}
```

You additionally need to use @TypeConverters annotation that defines the  Converts::class. If coded at the @Database level the converters have full scope.

So after `@Database(.....)` you could have :-

```
@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
```